# How to make an RNN model in PyTorch that has a custom hidden layer(s) and that is compatible with PackedSequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I want to make an RNN that has for example more hidden layers or layer normalization.

I know that is it possible to make a custom RNN by subclassing nn.module, but with this approach is it not possible to do efficient batch processing with a PackedSequence object (with variable length sequences) the same way and with the same efficiency as torch.nn.RNN.

I thought maybe the solution could be to subclass nn.RNN, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.